# Can't find the element after a page is changed for WSJ.com

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to log into WSJ.com. Below is the screen shot after sign in is clicked.
[page before the login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3M5h.png). After continue is clicked, it will bring me to the following page: [login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M67ow.png). This is where I have problem locate the input boxed to pass my username and password. Here is a screen shot of the html page: [login page html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEizB.png)

below is my code:

```
    username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'username')))
    user1 = "username"
    username.send_keys(user1)
    submit_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[@type='button'][@class='solid-button continue-submit new-design']")
    submit_button.click()
    
    #below code belong to the login page
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.get(driver.current_url)
    username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(driver.find_element_by_name("username"))
    password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'password')))
    username.send_keys(user1)
    pass1 = "password"
    password.send_keys(pass1)
```

Error I am getting

```
  File "main.py", line 74, in <module>
    username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(driver.find_element_by_name("username"))
  File "/Users/yizhangzhang/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 71, in until
    value = method(self._driver)
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not callable
```

Comment: Can we have at least email id to test it out from our end ?

Comment: 19000@wsjbg.com

Comment: @jjcloudjj just provide the direct link of the page where the issue has come for you

Comment: see if this works, https://sso.accounts.dowjones.com/login?state=g6Fo2SBrM2owX2RvZVhCZ2ZmSEVaVkxETHU5eWNnaXVwcm54YaN0aWTZIHJCZHFEWmFkc1VWbk1NcnpsUTVxczdHaThBTnV4dmNpo2NpZNkgNWhzc0VBZE15MG1KVElDbkpOdkM5VFhFdzNWYTdqZk8&client=5hssEAdMy0mJTICnJNvC9TXEw3Va7jfO&protocol=oauth2&scope=openid%20idp_id%20roles%20email%20given_name%20family_name%20djid%20djUsername%20djStatus%20trackid%20tags%20prts%20suuid&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.wsj.com%2Fauth%2Fsso%2Flogin&nonce=d7a8b6bb-8a03-4889-9f0c-4ad7d5de3301&ui_locales=en-us-x-wsj-215-2&ns=prod%2Faccounts-wsj#!/signin-password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are `two input fields` for `password` and `5 similar kind of HTML tags` for `Sign In button`, I have used xpath indexing to differentiate them.

**Sample code :**

```
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://sso.accounts.dowjones.com/login?state=g6Fo2SB2Zk91azNieEJhV3BSQy0zYnBXV1B5V282TzFWNWM2dqN0aWTZIGJLM05DYXBLMlp1Q25VUzFvNDNrVnByMHJldlRvOFFYo2NpZNkgNWhzc0VBZE15MG1KVElDbkpOdkM5VFhFdzNWYTdqZk8&client=5hssEAdMy0mJTICnJNvC9TXEw3Va7jfO&protocol=oauth2&scope=openid%20idp_id%20roles%20email%20given_name%20family_name%20djid%20djUsername%20djStatus%20trackid%20tags%20prts%20suuid&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.wsj.com%2Fauth%2Fsso%2Flogin&nonce=13e15baa-a157-469c-b4a5-8d6b167b44ab&ui_locales=en-us-x-wsj-215-2&ns=prod%2Faccounts-wsj#!/signin")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#username"))).send_keys('19000@wsjbg.com')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Continue']/.."))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//input[@id='password'])[2]"))).send_keys('Your password here')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//span[text()='Sign In']/..)[5]"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks life saver, when you say there are two input fields, when I searched for it, I could only locate 1, where did you find the second one?

Comment: You can check that in dom, go to inspect element and then look for password id, you would see two elements